# Popup menu in reorderable list is out of position

Tags: flutter, dart

Does anyone know why the PopupMenuButton renders at the wrong place when used in a ReorderableListView? It seems to render correctly when used inside a normal ListView.

Here is an example screenshot:

[image: Example of problem]

For those that want example code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(ListApp());
}

class ListApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ListAppState createState() => _ListAppState();
}

class _ListAppState extends State<ListApp> {
  List<String> items = [
    "Item 1",
    "Item 2",
    "Item 3",
    "Item 4",
    "Item 5",
    "Item 6",
    "Item 7",
  ];
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Reorder List'),
        ),
        body: Container(
          child: ReorderableListView(
              // child: ListView(

              onReorder: (oldIndex, newIndex) {
                int deleteIndex = oldIndex;
                items.insert(newIndex, items[oldIndex]);

                if (oldIndex > newIndex) {
                  // The old index is now 1 index higher
                  deleteIndex++;
                }
                items.removeAt(deleteIndex);
                setState(() {
                  items = items;
                });
              },

              children: items.map((item) {
                return Card(
                  key: Key(item),
                  child: ListTile(
                    title: Text(item),
                    trailing: PopupMenuButton(
                      itemBuilder: (context) {
                        return [
                          PopupMenuItem(
                            child: Text(item),
                            value: item,
                          )
                        ];
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
                );
              }).toList()),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Could it be that I'm using the PopupMenuButton the wrong way or is this Widget buggy?

I'd like my list to be sortable but the PopupMenuButton appearing at the wrong place is a problem.

Comment: The tooltip text that appears after long-pressing is also positioned (more) incorrectly, I think this is a bug that should be reported.

Answer (score 5):

It seems that the problem should be in the **ReorderableListView** widget's code, but in fact it's hidden in **PopupMenu**. To calculate popup position [this code](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/6c1a29e54c412d244256d9a23e7c1f0a76e2f0e1/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/popup_menu.dart#L1090) evaluates overlay's rendering box:

```dart
final RenderBox overlay = Overlay.of(context).context.findRenderObject() as RenderBox;
```

Because, by default, the `Overlay.of` method searches hierarchy for the nearest overlay, in case of **ReorderableListView** it returns internal overlay (one created to restrict dragging gesture) but for **ListView** it returns root overlay. Since the root navigator used to show popup menu, a shift appears in the former case.

Calling `Overlay.of` method with `rootOverlay: true` fixes the bug:

```dart
final RenderBox overlay = Overlay.of(context, rootOverlay: true).context.findRenderObject() as RenderBox;
```

Patching **Flutter SDK** is the most appropriate solution.

Comment: Good work, I had similar patch but less elegant! If I award you the bounty will you make a pull request for your solution? Thanks.

Comment: @kapace Not now, maybe next week. I have to investigate all possible combinations of `PopupMenu` options, because it can be used independently.

Comment: Hi, I'm facing the same issue. In my case, the first popup menu appears within the height of appBar no matter how much offset I set. I've used Two Tabbar and a ReorderableListView. I've tried all the possible solutions but no luck.

Comment: @ Teh Sunn Liu - this issue [fixed](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/pull/65832), but it is not yet in the stable branch-try switching to beta channel.

Answer (score 3):

I think this is as best as you can get it without tapping into the widget

[image]

```
             PopupMenuButton(
                  offset: Offset(0, 50), //add offset to fix it
                  itemBuilder: (context) {
                    return [
                      PopupMenuItem(
                        child: Text(item),
                        value: item,
                      )
```

Comment: Yeah I was messing around trying to figure it out and it seems like using Offset is the best way to go.

Comment: My biggest fear is that the size of the list might affect the offset. I'll try this out and see what happens as the list grows. Personally I think there is a bug in the ReorderableListView widget.

Comment: Size of the list will not affect the offset.. I tried that before answering. If you want to figure out what causing the popup menu being out then you can tap into the widget `ReorderableListView` and compare it with `ListView` which as you said works well with `PopupMenuButton`